# How to define the type of function with a parameter that accepts multiple types?

Tags: typescript

This is a simplified version of my code.
I want to define the type `HandlerFunctionType`.

```js
type Task = {
  ...
  handlerFunction: HandlerFunction;
}

const task1: Task = {
  ...
  handlerFunction: (value: boolean) => {
    // do something
    return true; // or false
  }
};

const task2: Task = {
  ...
  handlerFunction: (value: number) => {
    // do something
    return true; // or false
  }
};

const task3: Task = {
  ...
  handlerFunction: (value: string) => {
    // do something
    return true; // or false
  }
};
```

I was able to define like this:

```js
export type HandlerFunctionType =
  | ((value: boolean) => boolean)
  | ((value: number) => boolean)
  | ((value: string) => boolean);
```

Since this makes the code longer and they all are functions that return a boolean, I wanted to simplify by doing this:

```js
export type HandlerFunctionType = (value: boolean | number | string) => boolean;
```

But, this raises error:
`Type '(value: boolean) => true' is not assignable to type 'HandlerFunctionType'. Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible. Type 'string | number | boolean' is not assignable to type 'boolean'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.`

How can I simplify and group the types?

Comment: I think that you need to have a union of functions, your second type is not the same. The only thing I can come up with is this using generic helper type `type GenericFunction<T extends boolean | number | string> = (value: T) => boolean; type HandlerFunctionType = GenericFunction<boolean> | GenericFunction<string> | GenericFunction<number>`

Comment: What do you intend to *do* with such a type?  A union of functions corresponds to an *intersection* of parameters, meaning it's `(value: never) => boolean` and essentially *uncallable*.  Indeed if you only know a function accepts *only* one of `boolean`, `number`, or `string`, but you're not sure which, then you can't call it.  So on the face of it that's a union type.  Could you provide a [mre] showing how you intend to use the function or determine how to call it? Right now this looks like an XY problem since a union of functions by itself has essentially no use case.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're after. Are you looking for: `const HandlerFunction = (value: boolean | number | string): boolean => { /*do stuff*/ return true; }`?

Comment: The recent edit doesn't seem to address my question.  Unions of functions are essentially uncallable.  Are you assigning it and then *calling it*?  Show us a [mre] where you actually call the functions somewhere, please.  (If you never call the functions then `(value: never) => boolean` should "work")

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I have edited the 2nd time.

Comment: And yet you're still not demonstrating the functions being called.  Unfortunately I think we're at an impasse and I should disengage.  Good luck!

Comment: I checked where the function was called and realized what I was doing was totally messed up (it didn't make any sense). Sorry everyone if I wasted your precious time :( I'm closing this question since it won't be a real-life use case.

Answer (score 0):

In the simplified example you gave, you assign a new function to `handlerFunction` 3 times. After the last assignment, handlerFunction is of type `(value: string) => boolean`. This means that the only valid input type `string`.

When you define `type HandlerFunctionType = (value: boolean | number | string) => boolean`, it means that a function of type `HandlerFunctionType` receives a parameter that is *either* a boolean, a string or a number.

Since `handlerFunction` can only receive a string parameter, if you call `handlerFunction` with a different type, for example `handlerFunction(1)`, the behavior wouldn't be defined (as far as the TypeScript compiler is concerned). This is why the TypeScript compiler returns an error when you try to declare `handlerFunction` as a function of type `HandlerFunctionType`.

I assume you are trying to use [overload signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#overload-signatures-and-the-implementation-signature), and if so, the correct way to define `handlerFunction` would be:

```js
function handlerFunction(value: string): boolean
function handlerFunction(value: number): boolean
function handlerFunction(value: boolean): boolean
function handlerFunction(value: boolean | number | string) {
  // do something
  return true; // or false
}
```

And then you can define `HandlerFunctionType` like so:

```js
type HandlerFunctionType = {
    (value: string): boolean;
    (value: number): boolean;
    (value: boolean): boolean;
}
```

This way, `handlerFunction` will accept any of the three types as a parameter, and the types of `HandlerFunctionType` and `handlerFunction` will match.